# Contour integral $I = \int _{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1-x^3} dx$ parameterization signs conventions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> I was wondering about the signs convention while evaulating complex
>   contour integrals.
>
> I have an integral: $I = \int _{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1-x^3} dx$
>
> and my textbook encourages me to use following contour:

[image]

If I could parametrize the curve by myself, I would choose for that two semicircles negative signs and for that big one with the diameter $R$ plus sign, because I would choose the counter-clockwise direction. But why are $\varphi _2$, $\varphi_3$ and $\varphi_5$ all negative curves?

Does anyone know some good source concerning the parametrization for such curves?

EDIT: I can circle the semicircle in the opposite direction, so I have the same signs for them all.

Comment: Is the question about the principal value integral? If not, the integral diverges because of the pole at $x = 1$. For the p.v. integral, we want to integrate along the thick black line contour. Traversing that contour counterclockwise means traversing the small semicircles clockwise, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, it is a principal value.